# What is the best way to factor a value if modulo is used

Tags: modular-arithmetic, factoring, prime-factorization, discrete-logarithms

If i have the following values

$(1) m\prime=(r^e.m) \% n$

$(2) s\prime=(r.m^d) \% n$

If i have access to the value of $m$,$d$, $m^d$,$m\prime$,$s\prime$,$n$,$p=11$,$q=19$, $\phi=(p-1)(q-1)=180,$ and $e$. Is it possible to get the value of $r$, if yes what is the best way to do it?

Numeric example: 
$r=13$, $e=7$, $n=209$, $m=16$,$d=103$,

$m\prime= (r^e.m)\%n = (13^7 .16)\%209 =46$

$s\prime=(r.m^d) \% n=(13.16^{103}) \% 209 = 8$

Comment: I assume you also have $m'$, $s'$, and $n$? And may we assume that $\gcd(m,n)=1$?

Comment: yes, sorry about that. I will edit it

Comment: So after your edit, we still do not know $n$? And when you say we have $m^d$, do you mean we have $m^d\bmod n$ (for $m^d$ by itself can of course immediately be obtained from $m$ and $d$ anyway)?

Comment: regarding GCD(m,n)=1, no we cannot assume this. we have n (edited)

Comment: regarding $m^d$ we can have both $m^d$ and $m^d mod n$ because we have both of them. Can you give me sample steps using the numerical example if GCD(m,n)=1

Comment: If $\gcd(m,n)=1$, you can find the inverse of $m^d$ modulo $n$ by the extended Euclidean algorithm. -- Other special cases that can solve for $r$ may occur when the factorization of $n$ (or at least the value of $\phi(n)$) is known.

Comment: Thank you Sir. Yes we can assume to have $p$, $q$, $\phi(n)$. I edited the values and added it to the question. Another thing, this is related to RSA blind signatures, so do you know if it is possible to assume GCD =1 ?

Comment: I tried to solve it but it did not work with me, can i show you what i got?